# Gap between border and text

Tags: html, css, text, space

I don't know why I'm getting a big space between the top border of TextContainer and the text. (I do have a browser reset)

**CSS**

```
#TextContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="Container">
    <div id="TextContainer">
      <font>(Text)</font>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/UbVz7/)

Comment: And the reason in the fiddle there's more code is that when I erase it to make it simpler to visualise for you the gap disappears so it must be something in the rest of the code :P

Comment: you forgot to close you inner `div`

Comment: All divs look closed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the id container change:

```
display: block
```

to

```
display: inline-block
```

Here is the change I made:

```
#Container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 980px;
    height: 900px;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: top, opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;
    }
```

works here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/UbVz7/1/

To clarify the height auto and the block inline.

If you want to set the height to 400px like you have, you will need to set the display: inline-block as I have showed you above.

If you want to make the div auto which will take the size of the content added to the div then it is possible to add height: auto;

```
 #Cabeçalho {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
width: 980px;
height: auto;
background: #FFF;
}
```

This is because the height being set to 400px is pushing down anything that is in a block element to achieve its 400px.

The inline-block allows the data to overlap which pushes the text back up where you want it.

This is because of your overlapping effect.

With a block element when something does not fit, it is pushed to the next line.

Comment: Now the whole #Container is pushed downwards. In the first you can see the container almost touching the #Header, but now I think it's the Login, Register and Download li's who are pushing the #Container downwards.

Comment: Changed #MenuWrapper to inline-block and it fixed! Going to read some more "difference between inline block and block"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but if you change the height to auto, the space goes away.  Maybe an alignment issue?

```
 #Cabeçalho {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
width: 980px;
height: auto;
background: #FFF;
}
```